# Setting Variables on startup using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

via startup.py it is possible to execute python code when qgis starts.

Now I wonder, whether it is possible to set variable values, eg. a string variable which holds a path or a dictionary of values, which could be used by several plugins?

Comment: Hi, i think there must be several ways to achieve that ... if u're using Windows u can work with **environnement variables** that can be set and accessed by your python code ...

Answer (score 3):

You have to get acces to an instance of that plugin:

```
from qgis.utils import plugins
instance = plugins['plugin_name']
```

Then if you want to use some widgets from main window ex.:

```
value = instance.dlg.comboBox.currentText()
```

If you define a variable under `__init__`, you can use it with:

```
variable = instance.variable_name
```