# Avoid Python conflicts with the system environment (in Windows)

Tags: qgis, osgeo4w, shell

When are you new to QGIS and PyQGIS what works in the background you might be confused by the different Python Interpreters and customization by settings so called *environment variables*. 
How do avoid such conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

You do this by adding specific environment variables or s[tarting QGIS out of script what sets custom variables as it is done when you doing PyQGIS development](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116767/fixing-the-sdk-seems-invalid-error-when-setting-up-pycharm-and-pyqgis).

The environment variables aren't set by any installation process although the description allows such interpretation. If you want that QGIS uses different/additional [startup scripts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159397/setting-variables-on-startup-using-pyqgis#159404) or [plugins](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35517/is-it-possible-to-change-the-plugin-folder-location) you have to create the corresponding environment variables by yourself. This process is well descriped on [How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/51807/how-to-create-and-use-global-system-environment-variables/).
You can add custom variables in QGIS itself via [System Settings](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#id4) what even can override system's environment variables.

If you don't want to mess up with your standard (production) profile you may want to create an extra profile folder and [change the path default from default profile folder “.qgis2” to the new one].([How to change default path for ".qgis2" folder on Windows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151711/how-to-change-default-path-for-qgis2-folder-on-windows))